# Failed to parse plugin descriptor error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]

Tags: maven-3

mvn eclipse:eclipse

`Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9 (C:\Users\11111 \ .m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-eclipse-plug
n\2.9\maven-eclipse-plugin-2.9.jar): error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]`

deleted the repository folder and still facing the error.

Comment: Is there a `space` for the folder named `11111` and `.m2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems maven is corrupted .problem is solved by going to maven 3.0.3 version.